# How to push untyped metrics with multiple labels(key-value) using JAVA Prometheus Pushgateway client?

Tags: prometheus, client-library, prometheus-pushgateway

I want to push metrics using java PushGateway client.

**Sample PushGateway URL**
pushgateway.com:9091/metrics/job/job_name

**Sample Metrics**
metrics_name{instance="i1", label1="l1", label2="l2", label3="l3", label4="l4"} value

Can any one please provide me a code snippet to push the above metrics into Pushgateway using [Prometheus Java Simpleclient Pushgateway](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prometheus/simpleclient_pushgateway)?

**Note**
We have 20K ephemeral instances running of the application hence decided to use Pushgateway.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation of [PushGateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#url):

- To use the grouping key `job="directory_cleaner"`,`path="/var/tmp"`, the following path will not work:

```
/metrics/job/directory_cleaner/path//var/tmp
```

Instead, use the base64 URL-safe encoding for the label value and mark it by suffixing the label name with `@base64`:

```
/metrics/job/directory_cleaner/path@base64/L3Zhci90bXA
```

Here is an example of generating `url` from multiple key-value pair stored in `Map<String, String> groupingKey`:

```java
    String url = gatewayBaseURL;
    if (job.contains("/")) {
      url += "job@base64/" + base64url(job);
    } else {
      url += "job/" + URLEncoder.encode(job, "UTF-8");
    }

    if (groupingKey != null) {
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: groupingKey.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().contains("/")) {
          url += "/" + entry.getKey() + "@base64/" + base64url(entry.getValue());
        } else {
          url += "/" + entry.getKey() + "/" + URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8");
        }
      }
    }
    HttpURLConnection connection = connectionFactory.create(url);
```

[Github link](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/master/simpleclient_pushgateway/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/exporter/PushGateway.java#L279)